# AngularJS $http.post error in Internet Explorer <= 9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

I have the following bit of code, which works fine in every modern browser, but fails in Internet Explorer 9 and below.

```
authService.login = function(credentials) {
  return $http.post('https://example.com/login', credentials).then(function(res) {
    return res;
  }, function(err) {
    return err;
  });
};
```

`credentials` is an object that looks like this:

```
{
  username: 'john@example.com',
  password: 'smith'
}
```

The problem is that the POST never actually happens, instead it jumps straight to `return err;` and no error is even set. It says `Impossible d'effectuer l'opération à cause de l'erreur suivante c00c023e.`. The key being **c00c023e**, which is supposedly an encoding problem, but I don't see how that would completely prevent the call from happening.

The 'fix' is to use `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';` which does allow IE to POST, but my backend expects JSON so that doesn't help.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.22.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to make a cross-domain request?

Comment: Try sending a json , something like this {credentials:credentials}

Comment: It could be that these browsers do not support serializing to JSON `string`, try doing it on your own: `angular.toJson(credentials)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, it's cross-domain, but it works in every other browser.

Comment: If you're working with cross-domain, you need to ensure that both the server and client support CORS. In your case, it's likely that IEs <= 9 do not support CORS

Comment: see my answer about browsers supporting CORS and not supporting CORS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898876/the-concept-of-cors-and-should-i-enforce-an-origin-header/14909833#14909833

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments led me in the right direction, this was indeed a CORS issue. Turns out there is a simple and library agnostic fix provided by the [XDomain library](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain).

In the app making the CORS request, include the following script **before** any other scripts:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="http://example.com/xdomain/xdomain.min.js" data-slave="http://example.com/xdomain/proxy.html"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then, on the `example.com` domain, copy `xdomain.min.js` and create the `proxy.html` file that was defined above in the  `data-slave` attribute. The proxy file must contain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="xdomain.min.js" data-master="https://subdomain.example.com"></script>
```

Cross-domain requests will now work properly in IE9 and below. You could use XDomain for every browser rather than just IE by removing the conditional comment, but I doubt there is a significant portion of users using a browser that doesn't support CORS that also isn't Internet Explorer.